# nested loop without curly braces

Tags: c, for-loop, nested, curly-braces

Please help me my head is ready to blow

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
    unsigned short sum1=0;unsigned short counter=0;

    printf("Enter the number of integers you want to sum\n");scanf("%hd",&counter);
    for (unsigned int i=1;i<=counter;++i)
    { 
        printf("The i is %d and the sum is %d\n",i,sum1);
        sum1 =0;// 2 iteration sum =0;
        printf("The i is %d and the sum is %d\n",i,sum1);

        for(unsigned int j=1;j<=i;++j)
            sum1 =sum1+j;// 1 iteration sum=1;
        printf("The i is %d and the sum is %d\n\n",i,sum1);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Until now the book I read In the nested loops used to put curly braces But not in this 
example... 
Question 1) Why in the second iteration sum will be 3 and not 2 (I ask this because sum initializes to 0 before go to the nested for ) ? 
Question 2) Why when I want to printf() the j hits error ? 
Can anyone explain me EXACTLY HOW THIS PROGRAM WORKS ? 
I mean 1st iteration,2nd Iteration.... Thank you Brothers....

Comment: @haccks as much an improvement your edit makes to the code structure, I think it kind of takes away from the question, which was about understanding the confusing block of code. By reformatting it, you have removed most of the confusion.

Comment: @Jordan; I did this for OP.

Comment: @haccks That's fine, I'm not saying if I think what you did was bad or anything, but anyone else coming to this question for help might not understand what this question was really about. (Which is probably an unlikely event anyway :P )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
for (unsigned int i=1;i<=counter;++i)
{ printf("The i is %d and the sum is %d\n",i,sum1);
sum1 =0;// 2 iteration sum =0;
printf("The i is %d and the sum is %d\n",i,sum1);
for(unsigned int j=1;j<=i;++j)
sum1 =sum1+j;// 1 iteration sum=1;
printf("The i is %d and the sum is %d\n\n",i,sum1);}
```

is equivalent to:

```
for (unsigned int i=1;i<=counter;++i) { 
    printf("The i is %d and the sum is %d\n",i,sum1);
    sum1 =0;// 2 iteration sum =0;
    printf("The i is %d and the sum is %d\n",i,sum1);
    for(unsigned int j=1;j<=i;++j) {
        sum1 =sum1+j;// 1 iteration sum=1;
    }
    printf("The i is %d and the sum is %d\n\n",i,sum1);
}
```

This is because in `for-loop`s without braces, only the very next line is included in the loop.

Now in the first iteration, you will get:

```
"The i is 1 and the sum is 0"
"The i is 1 and the sum is 0"
"The i is 1 and the sum is 1" //Enters inner for-loop
```

Second:

```
"The i is 2 and the sum is 1" //Hasn't reset yet
"The i is 2 and the sum is 0" //Reset
"The i is 2 and the sum is 3" //Sum was 0, then added 1 when j was 1, 
                              //then added 2 when j was 2
```

Now, the reason you can't print j, is because your `printf` statements are all outside of your inner `for-loop`, so `j` is not defined :)

Comment: No it isn't equivalent... With {} prints more results.... I understand that the printf() inside the nested loop printed ONLY when i=j; And that the nested for every time is being initialized!!!! Is this Right?

Comment: @paulakis I _think_ you are misinterpreting how the `for-loop` structures work without braces. I don't believe there is a `printf()` inside the nested loop at all.

Comment: I have understand why sum take this values (My first question answered) I haven't understand why the j isn't visible

Comment: `j` is only in scope _inside_ the `for-loop` where it is defined. Once that loop is over, basically the `j` disappears. Because the loop with `j` is only around this line `sum1 =sum1+j;// 1 iteration sum=1;`, the `printf` is _outside_ the loop, therefore `j` does not exist.

Comment: Thank you my brother for your time.... I appreciate.... I can understand the scope with curly braces and when a variable is visible but in here.... HMHMHM Is somewhat weird... THank you ANYWAY

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Variable scope can be tricky, in my (limited) experience as a programmer, improving as a programmer only means that you encounter progressively trickier scope bugs ;)

Answer (score 1):

In C you cannot declare your variables inside a for-loop sequence:

`for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)` is wrong 
 And 
`int i;` 
`for (i=0; i<=10; i++)` is correct

Also you can say `int a,b,c=3;` instead of declaring them separately `int a, int b, int c=3;`

To help with your question ( I wish I could comment, but I need more reputation), if your statement (for, if, while) has just one (or none) operations to do, you don't need the curly braces: 
`for (i=0; i<=10; i++)` 
             `printf("%i ", i);`

When having more operations, you need a curly brace for the compilator to know how many of them are inside the for loop:

`for (i=0; i<=10; i++){` 
            `printf("%i ", i);` 
             `if(i%2==1)` 
                         `printf("Odd number");` 
          `printf("\n");` 
 `}`

Edit:
 `int i;` 
 `for(i=0; i<=10; i++){` 
      `int j = i+5;` 
      `printf("%i", j);` 
 `}` 
 Works very well, but `j` will not be available outside the for loop.

Comment: I know that you cant declare variables in the loops but with this trick -std=c99
 in the compiler this is working

Comment: It may be working, but it may be better to not start throwing random variables in every for, while. If you have a bigger code, this might actually hurt you as you might think that a variable is supposed to do something, but isn't because it's outside it's scope of view.

Comment: Who told you that a variable cannot be declared inside a for-loop?

Comment: I meant in the for itself, not in it's line of execution.

Comment: @paulakis In C89 you couldn't declare a variable in the "initialization statement", i.e. `for ( /* no declaration here */ ; ...)` C99 standard borrowed from C++ the ability to declare vars in almost any point in the code (not only at the beginning of a block, as in C89). This means that `for( int i = 1; .... )` is a perfectly legal C statement for C99 and later standards (i.e. not a "trick"). That `i` variable has limited scope: its scope begins just after the `=` sign and ends with the last statement of the `for` body.